# How to select any files from Gallery

Tags: android, attachment

I have a code ,in which i am able to select any image from gallery and attached it into my activity but i want same thing for any mp3 files or any text files as in attachement.

Here is my code:
    // b1 is my button.

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);


                startActivityForResult(i,SELECT_PHOTO);  
            }
        });
```

//  And returning result from Gallery:

```
@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                System.out.println("Path="+selectedImage);
                String[] filePathColumn = {     MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);cursor.close();

            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
             img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do for MP3

```
Intent pickMedia = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
pickMedia.setType("audio/*");
startActivityForResult(pickMedia,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

                }
            });

// And returning result from Gallery:

if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.register_photo);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
           }
```